# Read .ini file in python in windows OS

Tags: python

I am trying to wirte a script that reads a .ini file and then change the password value. As of now I am trying only to read a .ini file. I am using the below script , but once I execute, the cmd prompt just blinks and I cannot see any output. Please let me know if there are any solutions.

`import os`

`from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser`

`parser = SafeConfigParser()`

`parser.read('file.ini')`

`print parser.get('ID', 'PWD')`

Comment: This works fine for me. What does `file.ini` look like?

Comment: Also please explain how you are invoking the python script

Comment: @Kozyarchuk: I saved the file on desktop as mc.py and executed by double clicking the file.

Comment: @ grovesNL : The file looks like this.

Comment: `DSN=XXX;UID=xxx_app;PWD=xxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: I am trying to open different files from different folders and replace a word. I am using the below script to do it for 1 file. but how do I use for different files from different folders :

Comment: `import fileinput`
`for line in fileinput.FileInput(r"D:\Lavanya Jinde\test.ini",inplace=1):`
    `line = line.replace("MK$36@ngSF1","MK$36%ngSF2")`
   ` print (line,end='')`

Comment: I got it worked out. I wrote the below script and it works good. Just posting this, if this can be helpful to anyone.

Comment: `import fileinput, sys, os, shutil,time, datetime`
`old_password = input("Please enter old_password: ")`
`new_password = input("Please enter new_password: ")`
`logpath = 'D:\Lavanya Jinde\IFP password\Logs'`
`inputfilename = ['D:\Lavanya Jinde\IFP password\heartbeat\heartbeat.ini']`

Comment: `mydir = os.path.join(logpath, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`
`os.makedirs(mydir)`
`for file in inputfilename:`
 `shutil.copy2(file, mydir)`
 file = open(file, 'r')
 `text = file.read()`
 `file.close()`
 `for line in fileinput.input(inputfilename,inplace=1):`
  `line = line.replace(old_password,new_password)`
  `print (line,end='')`